# save the printable documetns in PCL-5e format using printer driver

Tags: c++, printing, vector, drivers, wdk

I want to develop a printer driver which should save the printable data into given location in PCL-5e format.

I have gone through bitmap example which comes with WDK example set. According to that sample, If we want to dump bitmap file output we need to hook [OEMEndDoc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff557715%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function and this will return [SURFOBJ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff569901%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) GDI structure which contains bitmap details.

Like wise, If We want to dump the data in PCL-5e format, Can any expert hint me which are the functions that I need to hook and which GDI structure returns PCL-5e data.

We can set the *Personality to "PERSONALITY_HPGL2" to configure the mini drivers to enable HP-GL/2. Other than this What are the main attributes I need to configure in GPD file.

Thank you,
Regards,
Robo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No GDI structure will give you PCL5e data. PCL5e is a printer description language (PDL) that is understood by your printer and not by Windows GDI.
However, the GPD based drivers (Microsoft Unidrv) do have support for PCL5e so this can be used for creating PCL5e job output.
You can use any of the WDK sample GPDs itself and the minidriver to see what your output would look like.
I am not clear on what printable data you want to capture. If you can provide more details, I can help you out.

Comment: Dear Nitin Thank you very much. I want to store the printing output(texts and geometry designs) in any of the vector format.Since WDK supports PCL5e and EMF, I choose PCL5e. Once we wrote the correct GPD file, Can you please explain me how to capture printing out put in PCL5e? through which interface/Function/Structure?

Comment: Dear Nitin, Could you please explain me what are the architectural/behavioral relationships between printer Driver, printer Spooler, Printer Processor, Printer Monitor, UniDrv, GDI, Postscript, Minidrivers, printer graphics DLL, printer interface DLL and rendering plugins? Which component plays at which point when we do a printing job? I am bit confused with all these names. Here for my purpose which component I need to develop? please refer this Question as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848188/wdk-printer-architecture

Comment: RoboAlex - some more questions... what is your input? Is it content (text, geometry design) you have in your custom application? Or is it content from a standard 3rd party windows application (like MS-Word, Excel, Photoshop etc). Since you said you wanted to develop a printer driver, I guess you may be looking at input coming from any standard Windows app. Is this correct?

Comment: @RoboAlex - on your other question. That is a whole lot of information to provide in a forum like this. Here are some links that would help you learn more on windows print subsystem, printer drivers and components

(1) http://www.undocprint.org/    (2) http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc783789%28WS.10%29.aspx    (3) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff560843%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: @Nitin - ya...Whatever the application which supports print function (like MS-Word, Excel, Photoshop etc..) could able to choose this printer(which I am gonna develop)and then that developed printer should save the contents in a vector format.(PCL will we good. if not emf is enough). so could you tell me how to save data in EMF format first?

Comment: @RoboAlex - so why dont you use the standard Microsoft Unidrv and create your minidriver that will output PCL5? You can check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff556567%28v=VS.85%29.aspx and the WDK samples for creating your driver very easily. Creating an EMF driver is a lot more difficult since you will need to implement all the driver entry points and then convert them to EMF.

Comment: @Nitin - Any Examples/tutorials which demonstrate about Developing Mini drivers other than form MSDN?

Comment: You can look at Microsoft WinHEC conference papers and tutorials. You need to google for them. One link I found was - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg497961. Other than that MSDN and the WDK driver samples are your best guide. If this helps, please do a (+1) :)